# Em qual diretório eu ponho os arquivos do meu site para serem acessados atraves do servidor web rodando em um container docker?

Tags: nginx, docker

Eu criei um container docker utilizando o docker-compose
O arquivo *docker-compose.yml* está no diretório */home//DockerFolder*. 
O arquivo está configurado da seguinte forma:

```
####
# ATENTION:
# Replace all occurences of sandbox with your project's name
####

# v2 syntax
version: '2'

# Named volumes
volumes:

# MySQL Data
sandbox-mysql-data:
 driver: local

services:
# MySQL (5.7)
mysql:
 image: mysql:5.7
 container_name: sandbox-mysql
 volumes:
  - sandbox-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
 ports:
  - "3306:3306"
 environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sandbox
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=sandbox
  - MYSQL_USER=sandbox
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sandbox

# PHP (with Nginx)
# you can change from nginx to apache, just change session 'image'
app:
 image: ambientum/php:7.2-nginx
 container_name: sandbox-app
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/app
 ports:
  - "80:8080"
 links:
  - mysql

# Laravel Queues
queue:
 image: ambientum/php:7.2
 container_name: sandbox-queue
 command: php artisan queue:listen
 volumes:
  - .:/var/www/app
 links:
  - mysql
```

Eu criei o arquivo index.php no mesmo diretório para testar o servidor, porem nenhuma informação foi retornada. O arquivo está no lugar certo? Como eu consigo visualizá-lo no navegador?

Comment: `/var/www/app`?

Comment: sim, eu li que esta pasta do container é mapeada em uma pasta no host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Resposta no caso apresentado fica em */home/DockerFolder*.